# How to throw SqlException Error as Connection NotEstablished

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

How can I display `SqlConnection` is not made?

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetData()
{
    try
    {
        var x = from n in db.Employee
                select n;
        return x.ToList();
    }
    catch (SqlException sq)
    {
        throw new SqlException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just throw the exception you caught?

Comment: throughing an Exception is better than Showing SqlConection not Established is Good?

Comment: You'll need to clarify. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Create a custom `Exception` class that inherits from `System.Exception`. Then use `throw new ConnectionException("Connection could not be established", sq)`. This constructor just passes the arguments to the `Exception`-constructor. So the original exception is preserved as inner-exception. Then you can catch this specific excpetion where you call `GetData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't create a new exception in the catch: 
you can manage the exception, for example to log the error and re-throw to manage the error in a upper level

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetData()
{
    try
    {
        var x = from n in db.Employee
                select n;
        return x.ToList();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

This code would be in the controller or in the service layer. For merely example proposal, I'm returning a object, but depending if it's an MVC application or Winforms, the message will flow to the users in different ways.

```
public object GetEmployees()
try 
{
   return employees.GetData();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   return new "An orror ocurred retrieveing data";
}
```

Comment: wen i write This Code why im Getting  Error as Notall code Implemented  public IEnumerable<Employee> GetData()
        {
            try
            {
              }
            catch (SqlException sq)
            {
                if (sq.Number == 40)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Connection Not Made...");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
           
        }

Comment: I don't understand the message. What is the exact message error?
In the other hand, you are creating new exceptions in the catch, section. Don't do dat. New exceptions hide the context of the original exception